# "New normal" grammatical or a joke word from social media?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Due to the pandemic covid19, some new words have popped up, especially this "**new normal"** word. Should it be replaced by just **"new norm"** rather than this relatively funny and irritating "**new normal"?**

Please let me know if this is **grammatical** as I have seen from the Google itself that even native English language users have used this "**new normal"** term. Not cool.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. You should explain in your question why you think "new normal" is "not cool".

Comment: I would guess that *normal* is far more familiar to most English-speakers than *norm*; and of course English loves to shift words among parts of speech.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"New normal" is correct, and has been used since well before the COVID19 pandemic

> 1 Mar 2009 - The new normal will be shaped by a confluence of powerful forces—some arising directly from the financial crisis and some that were at work long before it
>
> 9 Dec 2003 - The new normal: a SARS diary. Michelle Greiver.  This is what a quarantine looks like in 2003.
>
> 1998 N. Depraz, ‎D. Zahavi - It is now normal, and the old norm in relation to the new normal now becomes abnormal.

[Ngrams suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new%20normal&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnew%20normal%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnew%20normal%3B%2Cc0) a very sudden rise in this phrase in about 2000 (the earlier uses are false: they relate to "the need for a new normal school" in planning documents.)

By correct I mean that carefully edited writing, and careful speech by native speakers of English use this phrase. English is defined by its users. A phrase that is used and accepted cannot be ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

We frequently use "normal" as a noun to indicate "the normal or ordinary way of things."

This locution is used to claim that the the ordinary way of things will have to be *new*.

Comment: Yeah i know what "normal" means, but my point is if this is considered right to ear. This is a lousy word, they should use "new norm" instead.

Comment: @JohnArvin, so far all the comments and answers seem to disagree with your apparent assessment that the usage is not "right to ear".  "New normal" sounds okay to me, too (unlike "right to ear", which is not right to _my_ ear).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s grammatical and idiomatic. My dictionary labels it as (mainly?) [American English](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/the_new_normal) and my other dictionary (OED.com) indicates that this expression dates back at least to [1922](https://books.google.com/books?id=ArIHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA659&lpg=PA659&dq=The%20abnormal%20situation%20may%20persist%20until%20it%20becomes%20a%20new%20normal.&source=bl&ots=pxjWP5qQ_6&sig=ACfU3U2bvb4xdpPhMRTyU9H-59c3bwFs_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjztbKbzN_pAhUyoXIEHYhLAZoQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ), meaning that “new normal” is actually the *old* normal:

> The abnormal situation may persist until it becomes a new normal.

*Normal* is often a noun, with the examples that come to my mind being mostly in prepositional phrases: above/below normal, back to normal, etc.